# Picture does not fill the screen with the viewport height

Tags: html, ios, mobile

I have a storyboard containing a webview (full-screen) in which load the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="iFrame message passing test">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">

</head>

<body>
        <p>
            <img name="usaMap" src="facciata.png" usemap="#m_usaMap4" border="0" height="100%">
        </p>

        <map name="m_usaMap4">
            <area shape="poly" coords="416,550,410,850,793,870,781,552" href="">


       </map>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="ie8.polyfil.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           $('map').imageMapResize();

        </script>


</body>
 </html>
```

but the image facciat.png does not fit the screen height. Someone can help me?

Comment: Is the image cut off or is it just not filling the available space? Is there a reason you put the image in the paragraph tag? There's a few things that could be contributing to this.

Comment: the image is smaller than the screen , I believe in its original size. I followed this example: http://davidjbradshaw.com/imagemap-resizer/example/

Comment: Of course that the picture is not at a height of the screen. Even the example attached the picture is not at a height of the screen. This is the resolution of the image.

Comment: Oh ok. you want the image to go outside of the viewport to be the height of the screen?

Comment: I want that the image ( as in the example ) is a full screen but in this case not in width but in height

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there's a different way you can achieve this.

If you want the image to bleed off the screen to be as tall as the viewport, remove the `width="100%"` from the image tag.

Then either in css or like this

```
<img name="usaMap" src="facciata.png" usemap="#m_usaMap4" border="0" style="min-height: 100%; width: 100%;">
```

This will stretch to fill all of viewport but will look stretched. Remove the `width: 100%` if you don't want the stretched appearance.

Comment: ok i tried it , it is best but the image does not stretch within the screen

Comment: Are you trying this in iOS Webkit?

Comment: Here's an example. Seems to work in iOS as well as chrome and Safari. http://codepen.io/Trozdol/pen/VLoPod